# Adobe Flex Cairngorm - avoid singleton

Tags: cairngorm

Is there any way to avoid writing data to the singleton ModelLocator in Cairngorm?

In my current mxml files, I have something like

```
new LoginEvent(LoginEvent.GET_LOGIN_EVENT).dispatch();
```

And this fires off the event and command. In the command, we have something like:

```
public function result(data:Object):void
{       
  var returnedData:Array = data.result as Array
  model.login = returnedData;
}
```

Instead, I'd like to actually return the command result directly to the view. So, in the mxml file I have:

```
var loginResult:Array = new LoginEvent(LoginEvent.GET_LOGIN_EVENT).dispatch();
```

Which would necessiate the command changing to:

```
public function result(data:Object):array
{       
  var returnedData:Array = data.result as Array
  return returnedData;
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [ViewNotifications](http://www.gridlinked.info/cairngorm-secret-tip-3-responders-for-view-notifications/). The idea is to add IResponders to events, so they can be used like callbacks to send data back to the view.

Comment: Yup, I'd figurered this out already - just return the command's result via a callback to the view.